# Cannot pass token to a form in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I'm very new to angular and probably I'm doing something completely wrong.
I'm using two angularJs applications as I don't want to have any log in logic in my main application.

I'm trying to submit a regular HTML form by doing:

```
document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();
```

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" id="loginForm" action="Main.html">
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{regData.token}}"/>
</form>
```

The problem is that on a server "I'm not getting last regData.token value.

Here is the js code:

```
$scope.login = function () {
    $scope.regData.token = "Very Old data";
    $http
    .post('/authenticate', $scope.user)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.regData.token = "Very New Data";
        document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
        delete $window.sessionStorage.userName;
        alert(data);
    });
};
```

On a server I'm getting "Very Old data".
My assumption was that in success callback a new $scope is created, so I was trying to emit changes up, but with no luck.

Any idea how to get a new value "Very New Data"?

Any response is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In angular we use ng-model instead of val. Also I see you aren't sending the object in question. You are instead sending $scope.user which you have not defined. I would suggest reading more on angularjs forms before continuing -http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation

Comment: Dear Pbrain. You didn't read my code correctly. $scope.user is send as part of http request and loginForm is submitted after successful return of that call. $scope.user is defined somewhere else and not relevant to my problem at all. If I didn't send regData.token I wouldn't get "Very Old Data" on a server at all. Don't you think so?Second point: I also used ng-model with exactly the same result.